# Not able to retrieve the column names correctly with memcached

Tags: java, mysql, scala, memcached

I have a scala code to cache the MYSQL data using memcached. Below is the code.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient
import net.spy.memcached.AddrUtil
import net.spy.memcached.BinaryConnectionFactory
import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

object Memcachedtest 
{
  def MD5encode(query_line:String):String=
    {
        var md5:String=null;

        if (query_line == null) return null;

        try {
            val digest1:MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
             val hash:Array[Byte]  =digest1.digest(query_line.getBytes());
            val sb:StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(2*hash.length);

            digest1.update(query_line.getBytes());
            for(b <- hash)
            {
                sb.append("%02x".format( b&0xff));
            }
            md5=sb.toString();
        }
        catch 
        {
        case e:NoSuchAlgorithmException => e.printStackTrace();
        }
         md5
    }

  def memcache_get_result(mysql_table_statement:String)
  {
    var crsi:CachedRowSetImpl=new CachedRowSetImpl();
    var mem_client:MemcachedClient=new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(), AddrUtil.getAddresses("IP"))

         var obj:Object=null
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            val conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:IP","user","pass");
        val query_md5_res=MD5encode(mysql_table_statement);
             var future_object=mem_client.asyncGet(query_md5_res);
            try {
                obj=future_object.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch {

              case t:TimeoutException =>    future_object.cancel(false);
                System.out.println("Memcached timeout...");
            }
            if (obj==null) {
                System.out.print("Query result not in Memcached, ");
                var res:ResultSet = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(mysql_table_statement);
                crsi.populate(res);

                res.close();
                mem_client.set(query_md5_res, 10, crsi);
                while (crsi.next()) {

                  System.out.print("output : " + crsi.getString("COLUMN_ID"));
                }
                crsi.close();
            }
            else  {
                System.out.print("Query result in Memcached, ");
                var crsi_res_set:CachedRowSetImpl=obj.asInstanceOf[CachedRowSetImpl]
                System.out.println(crsi_res_set);
                crsi_res_set.beforeFirst();
                while (crsi_res_set.next()) {

                    System.out.print("output : " + crsi.getString("COLUMN_ID"));
                }
                crsi_res_set.close();
            }

        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
  }

   def main(args:Array[String])
    {
      var crsi:CachedRowSetImpl=new CachedRowSetImpl();
      var mem_client:MemcachedClient=new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(), AddrUtil.getAddresses("IP"))
      memcache_get_result("select statement")
      memcache_get_result("select statement")

        mem_client.shutdown();
    }


}
```

When I retrieve the result with `crsi.next()` the column names which I get with `crsi.getString(Columnname)` doesn't give the correct column name, suppose if I have two to three column name with A_ID,B_ID,C_ID all the column names are just ID instead of the prefix. So when I print it with crsi.getString(A_ID) there is no result.

The other weird thing is I have 2 eclipse, 1 has a maven build and other with sbt build, the one with maven build with scala code works fine, but the one with sbt build is giving this issue. Then the culprit should be CachedRowSetImpl class but both same JRE versions and the rt.jar points to same path for both the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the MYSQL JDBC version. SBT version had mysql jdbc version 5.1.5 and the other had 5.0.4 MySQL connector jar. Removed MYSQL jdbc jar and updated the library dependency with 5.0.4 for MYSQL connector jar.